# jQuery url after ajax redirection

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, redirect

Im trying to get the url of an ajax post made through jQuery api. The problem is the page I am sending data is doing a redirection and I need a way to get the redirected url. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Is it possiable to handle server side request. If so, you send some parameters to just send string in response then redirecting to another page. Using JS you can redirect to that page if need.

Comment: Duplicate of ["Capture redirect location of javascript XMLHttpRequest"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4465547/331508).

Comment: I have no control over the server side, so the only way is to figure out on the client side.