# Get redirected URL via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the redirected URL of a source. Example, this [URL](https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/2633428/):

```
https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/2633428/
```

Redirects to this [URL](http://www.tapread.com/book/index?bookId=91&chapterId=10725):

```
http://www.tapread.com/book/index?bookId=91&chapterId=10725
```

So I want to get the redirected URL (`http://www.tapread.com/book/index?bookId=91&chapterId=10725` one).

How can I do this via jQuery so the client (**not** server) *gets* the redirected URL?

EDIT:

So I need a function:

```
get_redirect_url('https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/2633428/');
```

Which would return:

```
http://www.tapread.com/book/index?bookId=91&chapterId=10725
```

Comment: `if( window.location.href === FROM ) { window.location.href = NEW_URL }`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want to get the **redirected** URL. So in my example above, I should be: `http://www.tapread.com/book/index?bookId=91&chapterId=10725`

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the current URL?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Please see my latest edit which should explain it.

Comment: Ah, you want to get the result of the redirect. Sounds more like [Capture redirect location of javascript XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4465547/215552) then.

Comment: You'd need to do this server side and check the response header for a 301 and the response domain. You can't do this client-side as the domain you've shown in the example doesn't have CORS headers in the response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there no *wild* workarounds, like loading the URL into a iframe and then after some time, *getting* the redirected URL? You get the idea...

Comment: No, you can't interact with a cross-domain iframe like that. You could do it using `postMessage()`, but this would rely on the third party actually writing the code to tell you the new domain. This seems massively unlikely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿ No, they're trying to get the URL that another site redirects to. They are not trying to perform the redirect.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8241461/1896761